# CSS - preventing child element inheriting cancelling out transform property of parent element

Tags: css, reactjs

I have found similar questions to this asked but none cover this specific scenario.  In my react app, on a card with image, text and a button, I want to have text and button appear conditionally on hover, have the image scale increase, and the image brightness decrease.  The problem is that when I hover over the button, the transform and filter properties on the image are cancelled.  Does anyone have a solution?

Here is the code in Card.js

```
const Card = (props) => {
    const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => {
        console.log("downloading sucka");
    };

    return (
        <div
            className="card"
            onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
        >
            <img alt="" src={props.url}></img>
            {hover && (
                <>
                    <div className="cardText">
                        <h4 className="username">{props.username}</h4>
                        <h4 className="title" style={{ fontWeight: "500" }}>
                            {props.title}
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <button className="downloadButton" onClick={handleClick}>
                        <a download href={props.downloader + "?force=true"}>
                            Download
                        </a>
                    </button>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

and here are the relevant parts from my Card.css

```
.card img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.03);
    filter: brightness(80%);
}
.cardText {
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
.downloadButton {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    background-color: #00000000;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 13px 5px 13px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.downloadButton:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: black;
}
```

big thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add the :hover to the card instead?

```
.card:hover > img {
  transform: scale(1.03);
  filter: brightness(80%);
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you ksav! :) I'll accept this answer in a moment